# 'No shipping information available' in Sales Order admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, order-grid, onestepcheckout

For few orders, `shipping description` in `admin order grid` shows

> 'No shipping information available'.

I am using the magestore `onestep checkout`. All I've found is that some orders have an empty `shipping_description` column in `sales_flat_quote_address` and 'sales_flat_order' table, where as shipping_method column is always correct. I tried to reproduce the same problem,but till now I haven't found any pattern yet.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Any solutions for this issue? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: We have had the same issue for years, but very rarely, but its been happening more recently. We also have onestep checkout

Comment: Any solution found for this issue. We also having this issue.